# Prerrellenar campos en formularios de elementor

Tags: html, wordpress, formularios, webforms, elementor

Estoy haciendo que un formulario salga prerrellenado al cargar la url.
http://pruebas.educasede.com/elementor-8/
Los campos a rellenar, con id `name` y `mensaje` los he intentado prerellenar con

```
http://pruebas.educasede.com/elementor-8?name=NombreEjemplo

http://pruebas.educasede.com/elementor-8?form:name=NombreEjemplo

http://pruebas.educasede.com/elementor-8?form-file-name=NombreEjemplo
```

Pero ninguna funciona. Gracias

código de inputs

```
<div class="elementor-form-fields-wrapper elementor-labels-above">
  <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-name elementor-col-100">
    <label for="form-field-name" class="elementor-field-label">Nombre</label><input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[name]" id="form-field-name" class="elementor-field elementor-size-xl  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="nombre"> </div>
  <div class="elementor-field-type-textarea elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-mensaje elementor-col-100">
    <label for="form-field-mensaje" class="elementor-field-label">Message</label><textarea class="elementor-field-textual elementor-field  elementor-size-xl" name="form_fields[mensaje]" id="form-field-mensaje" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos, ¿estás usando PHP? Por otro lado, estaría genial si pudieras incluir un poco de código (por ejemplo, el HTML con los inputs)

Comment: He editado el código del HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes prerrellenar los input usando el campo `value`.

Supongamos que tienes los dos inputs dentro de un form. Mediante el `value`, puedes darle un valor por defecto. Entonces, usando PHP, puedes asignar a `value` la variable global `$_GET`.

El segundo input es más complicado, pues los `textarea` no incluyen un `value`. Para tener por defecto un valor, debe escribirse entre la etiqueta de abertura y clausura del `textarea`.

Algo así debería funcionar:

```
<form>
  <input name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
  <textarea name="mensaje"><?=$_GET['nombre']?></textarea>
</form>
```

En el caso de que no usaras PHP, algo así podría hacerse en JS. Podrías conseguir los parámetros GET usando [alguno de estos métodos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript/). Entonces, para el primer input, podrías cambiar su value usando algo así:

```
document.getElementById('name').value = //aquí el valor obtenido del GET
```

Y para el segundo, el textarea, lo único que se me ocurre es usar el innerHTML para insertar ahí el textarea.

EDITADO:

Ahora que has compartido tu código, te pongo en tu mismo código lo que te expliqué arriba, con PHP.

```
<div class="elementor-form-fields-wrapper elementor-labels-above">
  <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-name elementor-col-100">
    <label for="form-field-name" class="elementor-field-label">Nombre</label><input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[name]" id="form-field-name" class="elementor-field elementor-size-xl  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="nombre" value="<?=$_GET['name']?>"> </div>
  <div class="elementor-field-type-textarea elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-mensaje elementor-col-100">
    <label for="form-field-mensaje" class="elementor-field-label">Message</label><textarea class="elementor-field-textual elementor-field  elementor-size-xl" name="form_fields[mensaje]" id="form-field-mensaje" rows="4" placeholder="Message"><?=$_GET['mensaje']?></textarea>    </div>
</div>
```

Prueba si esto funciona, para ello inténtalo con este enlace: http://pruebas.educasede.com/elementor-8?name=NombreEjemplo

Comment: Gracias @Tupi pero lo que necesito es enviar una url que al pinchar en ella acceda al furmulario con el campo prerellenado. Estilo https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScbgWqFWWYgmpDMtRhAyJd7opNij4L_docN_XL9IU2h6nqWfQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1137936653=PruebadePrerrellenado

Comment: Si no entendí mal tu pregunta, eso es lo que necesitas. En tu caso, quieres prerellenar eso así: `http://pruebas.educasede.com/elementor-8?name=NombreEjemplo`. Si te fijas, el enlace incluye un `?name=NombreEjemplo`. Ahí acabas de decirle a la página web: "oye, `name` es igual a NombreEjemplo". Con PHP, puedes obtener ese valor usando `$_GET['name']`. Con JS, te adjunté el proceso en la respuesta.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta, la actualicé con el código que deberías poner.

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes acceso al código del formulario, podrías llenarlo con JavaScript, usando la función wp_localize de wordpress, aquí un ejemplo

Primero crea tu url, tipo, https://dominio.com/?nombre=NameHere&last-name=LastName&id=1

Esta url devuelve tres datos
nombre = NameHere
last-name = LastName
id = 1

La url la construyes como desees, puedes detectar la sesión y pre rellenar en enlace, entonces lo que restaría seria recuperar esa información.

lo primero es crear una función como esta:

```
function rellenarForm() {
        // Encolamos el archivo archivo
        wp_enqueue_script( 'archivo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/archivo.js', false, '1.0', true );
        // Enviamos las variables al archivo
        wp_localize_script('archivo', 'user_data', array(
                'nombre'    => $_GET['nombre'],
                'last_name' => $_GET['last_name'],
                'id'        => $_GET['id'],
            )
        );
    }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rellenarForm', 99 );
```

Crea y agrega la ruta correcta de tu archivo.js, puedes ponerle el nombre que quieras, luego en tu archivo js puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Obtenemos los datos
    const name = user_data['nombre'];
    const last_name = user_data['last_name'];
    const id = user_data['id'];

    // Los agregamos a los valores de los inputs
    jQuery( 'input.input-name' ).attr( 'value', name  );
    jQuery( 'input.input-last-name' ).attr( 'value', last_name  );
    jQuery( 'input.input-id' ).attr( 'value', id  );

});
```

Lo importante es que debes de conocer la clase o id del input para poder asignarle el valor y también conocer previamente el nombre de las variables php para poder obtenerlas, con eso no deberías de tener problemas, esto va en tu archivo functions.php, no esta de mas trabajar en un tema hijo o un plugin de snippets